# Why isn't angular displacement called angular distance?

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, terminology, circles, classical-mechanics

Consider a unit circle.

Define:

- angular displacement: $\phi=\theta_1-\theta_2$;
- angular position: $0\leq\theta<2\pi\;$ s.t. $\;\phi\equiv_{2\pi}\theta$;
- minor arc length: $m=
  \begin{cases}
  \theta, &\text{ for } 0<\theta<\pi,\\
  2\pi-\theta,      &\text{ for } \pi<\theta<2\pi.
  \end{cases}$

To my mind:

- the angular analogue of linear displacement is $m$;
- the angular analogue of linear distance is $\phi$.

So why is $\phi$, as defined here, called angular displacement rather than angular distance?

[image]

Comment: Note that unlike distance, $\phi$ has some degree of directionality in that it can be either positive or negative